# AccountVMSeriesCoreQuotaReached Even the Quota is Increased in Azure Batch Pool

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, azure-batch, azure-vm

I am trying to create an Azure Batch pool using the below specs.

Region: East US 2

VM Series: Basic A Series

When I create the Batch Acc, I am getting the below error.

> Code: AccountVMSeriesCoreQuotaReached
> The specified account has reached VM series core quota for basicAFamily

I created a support request and Increased the quota for 100 VMs as below. Currently, it supports 100 VMs.

[image: Azure VM Quota]

However, still, I am getting the above error for the below specs.
[image: Error]

And the Batch Account is in East US 2 as well.
[image: BatchDes]

Am I doing anything wrong here? How I can get rid of `AccountVMSeriesCoreQuotaReached`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you increase it for the specific series?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Yes. The answer you added and recently deleted was correct. That was the issue !!!

Comment: ok enabled answer again! haha i read the question again and thought you've already done it. Mark if that helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a subscription, Azure Batch has its own set of quotas which is separate from the subscription-wide quotas

Go to: `Batch accounts => <name of batch account> => Quotas`

And increase it

Comment: Note that this is only true for Batch accounts with pool allocation mode of `Batch managed`. `User subscription` Batch accounts inherit per VM family quota from the subscription that the Batch account resides in.